# Склонение названий иностранных клубов

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, склонение

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно склонять названия иностранных спортивных клубов?

Например: товарищеский матч с *"Урава Ред Даймондс"*, или с *"Уравой Ред* *Даймондс"*, или с *"Урава Ред Даймондсом"*?
По аналогии: матч с "Миланом", с "Реалом", с "Баварией" и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Матчи с "Монреаль Канадиенс", "Детройт Ред Уингс" и т.п. Хотя, естественно, матчи с "Монреалем" и "Детройтом", имея в виду те же клубы.

Comment: Благодарю!.....

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: ***товарищеский матч с "Урава Ред Даймондс"***.

Дело в том, что имена собственные, состоящие из нескольких слов, обычно не позволяют отнести их к какому-то определенному роду автоматически, "по внешнему виду". И тут обычно вступает в силу правило родового слова.     "Урава Ред Даймондс" - команда, то есть женского рода. Имена собственные женского рода, оканчивающиеся на согласный, в русском языке не склоняются.

Если же такое название принадлежит не команде, а клубу (кораблю, фильму) и заведомо имеет мужской род единственного числа, склонение в разговорной речи становится возможным: *Я плыл на "Романс-ов-тзе-сизе" (Romance of the Seas)* - в русском "корабли" мужского рода, а "суда" - среднего.

Но самым правильным в таких случаях будет добавлять родовое слово (Клуб "Монреаль Канадиенс", вечеринка "Техно Мэйкс Сэнс"). В этих случаях иностранное название никогда не склоняется, а русские - только при единичных случаях родового слова ("в городе Москве").

Comment: Благодарю! А если союсвенные название мужского рода, например клуб "Рот-Вайсс Эссен", превратится в:  матч с "Рот-Вайсс Эссеном"?

Comment: @ДжекиЧай В примере с Эссеном - да. Звучит вполне нормально на русский слух. Это не обязательно, но такое возможно, особенно в разговорной речи. Но только если это матч **с клубом**. В русском понимании матчи обычно бывают между **командами** клубов. Еще может сказаться грамматические род и число оригинального названия и язык оригинала. Так, названия американских и канадских клубов в оригинале обычно имеют множественное число.  Это тоже в некоторой степени препятствует склонению.

Comment: ***имена собственные***, простите. У меня была опечатка.