# Согласование при склонении названий зарубежных клубов

Tags: согласование, названия

Вопрос по склонению названий зарубежных клубов, в которых первое слово женского рода, напр.: "Миннесота Тимбервулвз", "Филадельфия Флайерз".

Нужно ли склонять первое слово? Игроки "Филадельфия Флайерз" или "Филадельфии Флайерз"?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Склонение названий иностранных клубов](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432538/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2)